# C# compare object array to bool

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function which will return me an object array with different types in each element.
This is a small reproducer of what i am trying to achieve.

```
public static object[] asset()
    {
        object[] tab = new object[11];
        tab[0] = bool;
        tab[1] = int;
        tab[2] = int;
        tab[3] = int;
        tab[4] = int;
        tab[5] = int;
        tab[6] = string;
        tab[7] = double;
        tab[8] = float;
        tab[9] = int;
        tab[10] = ""; //string
        return tab;
    }
    object[] testobject = new object[11];
    testobject = asset();
    If (testobject[0] = true)
    {

    }
```

So i am trying to performe a bool check to the object[0] which is a bool. Obviously it doesn't work like this. I tried converting object[0] to boolean and then test it which is what i do for integers or doubles but it doesn't work neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: `If (testobject[0] = true)`, use lower case if and use `==` to compare, not `=`.

Comment: having an array of object with different types is really bad practise. you should rather declare a variable for each value.

Comment: Why do you need an array of objects of different types instead of defining a specific class that contains a property for each object of the appropriate type?

Comment: I have a lot of array objects with different values. I think i save a lot of coding using arrays of objects. And besides that i can change the objects value to whatever i want whenever i want. That is why i bear with array objects

Comment: No, you **don't** want to use an array to hold a bunch of different types. You're missing the point of object-oriented programming. Create a class that contains the properties you want to have available, which gives you type-safety, intellisense, and a whole slew of advantages over an array of `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to cast before checking, although it is hard to say as you have some compile errors in your code.

```
if ((bool)testobject[0] == true)
{

}
```

Notice the use of `==` instead of `=` (which is an assignment).

You can even shorten this to:

```
if ((bool)testobject[0])
{

}
```

Comment: I tried Convert.ToBoolean() but it threw me an exception that it was not possible to convert it to boolean. Now it works. Dont know why... Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

`object[0] is bool` will produce `true` if it is a `bool` and `false` if not.

```
if (object[0] is bool) 
{
    bool myBool = (bool)object[0];
    // do something with myBool
}
```

If you use:

```
bool? myBool = object[0] as bool?;
```

then `myBool` will be `null` if the value was not a `bool` and it will have a boolean value if it was.

```
bool? myBool = object[0] as bool?;
if (myBool != null)
{
    // do something with myBool
}
```